# Checking if the trigger exists before executing a query

Tags: triggers

I want before executing the following query

```
alter trigger my_trigger disable
```

check if the trigger exists or not

How can I check if the trigger exits ? (RDBMS: oracle)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
select * from sys.triggers where name = 'My_Trigger'
```

Querying Information_Schema would be ideal, but I'm not sure trigger information can be found there.